How to instruct Clang to populate offset based on Fixed Segment Addresses in AArch64 assembly?
I'm working on an aarch64 code analysis project where I need to use clang to convert aarch64 assembly code into bytecode, and then use llvm-objdump to extract and analyze the bytecode. Additionally, I need to fix the segment addresses and populate the offsets in the assembly accordingly, and the text segment address should be set as 0x40000, the data segment as 0x50000, and the bss segment as 0x60000.
However, when I compile the following code using the command:
.text
.globl main
main:
    adrp x0, var1
    ldr w1, [x0, :lo12:var1]
    adrp x2, var2
    ldr w3, [x2, :lo12:var2]
    ret
.data
.globl var1
var1:
    .zero 8
    .size var1, 8
.globl var2
var2:
    .zero 8
    .size var2, 8

clang -c -target aarch64-none -march=armv8.1-a -Ttext=0x40000 -Tdata=0x50000 -Tbss=0x60000 test.s -o test.o

clang gives the following warnings:
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-Ttext=0x40000' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-Tdata=0x50000' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-Tbss=0x60000' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]

Also, when I use llvm-objdump-15 -d test.o, the result shows that the instruction offsets are not filled as expected:
test.o:       file format elf64-littleaarch64

Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <main>:
       0: 90000000      adrp    x0, 0x0 <main>
       4: b9400001      ldr     w1, [x0]
       8: 90000002      adrp    x2, 0x0 <main+0x8>
       c: b9400043      ldr     w3, [x2]
      10: d65f03c0      ret

Using llvm-objdump-15 -r test.o to print relocation information also shows that the segment addresses provided during compilation are not used:
test.o:       file format elf64-littleaarch64

RELOCATION RECORDS FOR [.text]:
OFFSET           TYPE                     VALUE
0000000000000000 R_AARCH64_ADR_PREL_PG_HI21 var1
0000000000000004 R_AARCH64_LDST32_ABS_LO12_NC var1
0000000000000008 R_AARCH64_ADR_PREL_PG_HI21 var2
000000000000000c R_AARCH64_LDST32_ABS_LO12_NC var2

How can I make clang recognize the fixed segment addresses and populate the relocation information in the compiled instructions accordingly?
Update: I'm facing a lot of cross-compile issues without the -c option. Therefore, is there any way to pre-populate the instruction without having to compile it to a real program?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Segment addresses and offsets are only determined during the linking step, so... drop the -c.

Thanks for the comment! However, the segment would not compile without -c:  /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/t1-f54489.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 183) /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/t1-f54489.o: error adding symbols: file in wrong format collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status clang: error: linker (via gcc) command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) ``. Therefore, are there other ways to pre-populate the instruction without having to compile it to a real program?

Just install lld and use -fuse-ld=lld.

Attempting to use lld, I've encountered cross compiling issues like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72055376/clang-failed-to-invoke-lld-correctly and I solve it using aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc. Thanks for the instruction!
